# Codeigniter - If data is seen on page, update database (Not Working)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an announcement page. If an user sees the announcement, the user id of the user, announcement id of the announcement and the date is inserted in the `announcements_seen` table. If the announcement id and the user id is not found in that table, then the user who is currently logged in will get an alert on every page he visits saying that he as a new announcement.

After the page loads, I am able to insert the data (user id, announcement id and date) in the table so that the alert goes away since there are no "unread" announcements. However, it is not working properly. It will only work if my `a_uid` column has the user id of the current user, and the `a_aid` column has the announcement id of all the announcements, to mark as read in my table.

The the announcement id and user id is not present in my table, then it will show the alert.

**The Problem:** Everytime a new user registers and views an announcement, his user id and the announcement id is also posted in the database. But the user 1 also sees that he has pending announcements even though he has viewed all the announcements already. If I change the second user's uid from the table to the 1st users uid, user 1 has no problem.

Sorry if it's hard to explain.

My code:

```
//check for unread anouncemnts
$this->db->from('announcements_seen');
$this->db->join('announcements', 'announcements.aid = announcements_seen.a_aid', 'right' );
$this->db->where('aid !=', 1);
$this->db->where('a_uid ', NULL);
$this->db->or_where('a_uid !=', $uid);
$announcements_query = $this->db->get();

if ($announcements_query->num_rows() > 0) {
//show alert
}
```

Comment: Please show us what SQL STATEMENT you want, we can convert in Codeigniter.

Comment: Is the prboblem for Insertion or Select query while fetching? use $db->last_query() and compare it with your Expected SQL statement.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com the problem is selecting query. I want to select data from database and then check if the user has already seen it before or not and then show the alert after